# How many rounds of escaping are needed in Git alias configuration?

Tags: bash, git, sed

I have this row in my .gitconfig, and there is a lot of \

```
[alias]
    alias = "!git config -l | egrep ^alias | sed -e s/alias.\\\\\\([^=\\ ]\\\\+\\\\\\)=/\\\\1\\ =\\ /"
```

for rexemple the `\\\\\\(` is just start of group in rexep, if it was supose to match the character (, it whould need another layer of escaping.

and the dot after alias should proberly have some slashes to, but how many?

If someone can make a list that explain where in the process each layer of escape characters gets removed, I may get a bit more understading of whats happening.

1. How many \ should there be before the dot after alias?
2. why?

Edit 1, exemple data:
`grep alias ~/.gitconfig  -A 6`

```
[alias]
    alias = "!git config -l | egrep ^alias | sed -e s/alias.\\\\\\([^=\\ ]\\\\+\\\\\\)=/\\\\1\\ =\\ /"
    blog = log --graph --oneline --decorate --all --simplify-by-decoration
    flog = log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
    test = !composer test
    require = !composer require
    update = !composer update
    install = !composer install
```

Exemple output `git alias`

```
alias = !git config -l | egrep ^alias | sed -e s/alias.\\\([^=\ ]\\+\\\)=/\\1\ =\ /
blog = log --graph --oneline --decorate --all --simplify-by-decoration
flog = log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
test = !composer test
require = !composer require
update = !composer update
install = !composer install
```

Exemple output `git config -l` (intresting rows only)

```
alias.alias=!git config -l | egrep ^alias | sed -e s/alias.\\\([^=\ ]\\+\\\)=/\\1\ =\ /
alias.blog=log --graph --oneline --decorate --all --simplify-by-decoration
alias.flog=log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
alias.test=!composer test
alias.require=!composer require
alias.update=!composer update
alias.install=!composer install
```

Comment: A text that starts whit "alias." and up until a "=", it's removes the prefix and put spaces around the " = ", works now, but it may hit some false positives, as the dot is matched as any character

Comment: I found that calling script files (have a ~/bin in your path) from places like this is much easier to understand than trying to squeeze direct commands through quoting and escaping hell. Nobody can parse more than a layer or two of quoting, and the errors are subtle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Since you are writing a command in a double-quoted string, you need to use `\\` instead of `\`.
2. Since you are not single-quoting your sed command, you need to include extra (double) backslashes.

You can mitigate the problem by quoting your sed command, and by using `-E` to reduce the need for backslash-escaped capture groups:

```
alias = "!git config -l | sed -nE 's/^alias\\.([^= ]+)=/\\1 = /p'"
```

Note that I also used `sed -n` with a `p` flag to avoid the need to use grep.

Comment: So you reduced the need of escape to seds \. and \1, and becuse i used " in the config file, the \ need to be \\. Adding a ^ infrony of alias and using that one, thatnks

Comment: Can you further reduce the escaping by using single instead of double quotes, e.g `alias = '!git config -l | sed -nE '\''s/^alias\.([^= ]+)=/\1 = /p'\'''`?

Comment: @Ed I tried messing around with quoting but couldn't get it to work with single quotes - it seems that a single-quoted string is interpreted as a single word rather than a list of tokens.